# `sudo rm -rf /` got interrupted leaving the data partially deleted

Tags: sudo, rm

I ran `sudo rm -rf /` to wipe out all data, for some reason the execution got interrupted.
Now I am left with a shell that only has `cd` command!!! (`ls`, `sudo`, `rm`, etc got deleted!)

What should I do to continue the deletion????

Thanks

Comment: format the drive :)

Comment: Erm, how? (I no longer have the OS disk)

Comment: What dist are you using? There are ways to format a drive without a disk. Hook it up to another machine, etc.

Comment: `ubuntu 13.0.4` (and half of the stuff has been gone due to the `rm` command. Now the ONLY command that is still there is `cd`)

Comment: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop

Comment: By the way, what makes you think it was interrupted? It sounds like it worked perfectly,

Comment: I know it got interrupted because I accidentally pulled the power plug! (meant to pull the other one)

Comment: Ah, yes, that will do it :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Never, ever run `rm /` on a working system. What were you thinking? Of course you don't have anything left, the only things remaining are commands like `cd` that are not separate binaries but inbuilt commands of your shell (`bash` probably).

I assume you wanted to clear out the drive in order to install or reinstall an operating system. If so, just shutdown and install as you would normally. You will be asked to format the drive and I recommend you do so.

If you thought you were deleting something other than your main OS dirve (the equivallent of `C:` in Windows), I am afraid you were wrong and have completely borked your system. Whatever your original aim, you will need to reinstall.

For future reference it is never a good idea to wipe a drive that contains the OS you are currently running. Next time, if you want to completely clear out the partition that contains your OS, boot into a live CD or another OS and format it from there.

Comment: I wanted to wipe out the data *completely*

Comment: And I don't care if the OS got deleted. ... I just needed the data to be gone (so I can take the machine out of the building).

Comment: @OneTwoThree that's what formatting is for. In fact, it is a much better way of wiping than simple deletion which simply unlinks the file. Neither are 100% secure though, if that is what you want look into ways of overwriting every sector of the drive with random data. In any case, never do this to a running system.

Answer (score 1):

Get [Darik's Boot And Nuke](http://www.dban.org/), burn it to a CD, boot that CD and properly delete the contents of your drive.

You can also put [DBAN on a USB drive](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/install-dban-to-a-usb-flash-drive-using-windows/) if that makes it easier.